# Excel Hyperlink to a specific page in word

Tags: excel

Can any one please explain me how we can add hyperlink from excel cell to a specific page in word document.

Ex: 
     I have 3 columns in my excel namely C1 , C2 and C3. I have a word document named as      'System_Ref.docx'.

When user clicks on C1, `System_Ref.docx` should be opened with page number 10. In the same way, when user clicks on C2, `System_Ref.docx` should be opened with page number 18...etc.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that this cannot be done just like this. There are quite some questions asked to the same extend. But even on the official MS website you will not find a switch for that:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-word-2007-HP010164010.aspx

The command line way is to have bookmarks in your word document beforehand and a macro that gets triggered when opening the file. However this isnt a real solution for random Word documents or documents that come from an outside source...

Alternatively you could write a macro in Excel that uses some settings in your cells that opens the Word document and then use a `.PageScroll 10` to scroll to page number 10.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Is it possible if my word document has required bookmarks and then I can refer to any of those marks from different coloumns in excel like C1 and C2..etc

Comment: With the bookmarks you will also need a macro in your word document which you will have to include in your command line command (hyperlink might not be the right term here anymore).